# Relative speeds of TelephonyManager's types?

Tags: android, network-programming, telephonymanager

There are a number of network types defined in TelephonyManager:

```
NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS
NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE
NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS
NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA
NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0
NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A
NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT
NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA
NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA
NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA
```

Is there any info out there that describes what range of speeds you can expect on each of these?  If that isn't available, it would be nice to be able to order them based on speed.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wireless_data_standards#Throughput). It's fairly good, and has some convenient tables for ordering them.

The (general) ordering based on speed would be approximately:

```
NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS  #Slowest
NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT
NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA
NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE
NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS
NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0
NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A
NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA
NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA
NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA  #Fastest
```

There's some wiggle room here, though. Particularly at the lower end of the spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget some are CDMA/3GPP2 and some are GSM/3GPP

You are unlikely to get both on the same phone.

Thus you should have two lists:
GSM/3GPP:
GPRS
EDGE
UMTS
HSPDA
HSPUA
HSPA

CDMA/3GPP2:
1xRTT
CDMA
EVDO 0
EVDO A
EVDO B